# NSMutableArray strange crash - removeObjectAtIndex

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsmutablearray

I received a crash from one of my app which appears weird with following logs:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 4294967293
>   beyond bounds [0 .. 4294967293]'

As per stack trace this is coming from below piece of code:

```
if ([self.itemList count] > 0) {
    [self.itemList removeAllObjects];
}
```

Per my understanding, `removeAllObjects` is always a safe operation and should not end up in a crash like this. Am I missing something over here. Any guidance to right direction would be really helpful.

**EDIT**:

Here is my `itemList` property declared:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *itemList;
```

Comment: and how to allocate that array ?

Comment: Try this condition : if([self.itemList isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]]){//remove object here}

Comment: Are you really sure the crash is from those lines of code? Do you have other code that calls `removeObjectAtIndex`? Is your code multi-threaded?

Comment: @KKRocks If you read the error then you know the array is an `NSMutableArray`.

Comment: @rmaddy - Yes it is multi-threaded. And at least from the stack trace, it is pointing to these lines.

Comment: Then you may be making other changes to `self.itemList` while the call to `removeAllObjects` is running. You need to ensure no two threads can read/write the array at the same time.

Comment: I think nonatomic to atomic will solve issue if it is thread issue, as it will allow only one read or write at a time . or apply lock

Comment: Actually, making `itemList` atomic does not make the mutable array thread safe. If `itemList` is being mutated on a different thread making the property atomic will not help. You'll need to access `itemList` in a thread safe way using a queue, locks, or synchronization

Comment: Are you doing this in [self dealloc] method?

Comment: @MikeAlter No, that won't help at all. In addition to Peter's comment, making a property atomic does not in any way synchronize access to the data represented by the property. It only ensures that assigning / reading the property's value is atomic. That's a big difference.

Comment: By the way @Abhinav how you filled object in self.itemList.
Please check once may be your self.itemList array become immutable ,when you copy items from other array.

Answer (score 0):

It is most likely caused by the property being non-atomic. As you mentioned this code is multi-threaded and you are using a property which is not thread safe.

> - Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '* -[__NSArrayM removeObjectAtIndex:]: index 4294967293 beyond bounds [0 .. 4294967293]'

This error simply means that the object that has to be deleted is already deleted and hence the returned index is '4294967293.' Try to set the array to atomic. Also try using @synchronized as mentioned in a similar question here:

[NSMutableArray removeAllObjects beyond bounds exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15767093/nsmutablearray-removeallobjects-beyond-bounds-exception)